# How to convert For loop to apply

Tags: r

How do I convert the below nested For loop to an Apply?

```
for(i in 1:length(vList$Subgroup.Number))
{
  for(j in 1:length(viol_grp))
   {
    viol_List[[j]] <- vList[which(vList$Subgroup.Number==viol_grp[j]), ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried lapply(viol_List, vList[which(vList$Subgroup.Number==viol_grp[j]), ] ), I got an error it says that its not a function.. I am not aware how do I form a function to sort this out.

Comment: Good! Add this information to your question for other users see what you tried and what kind of error you got. They will be more willing to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

The first loop is not necessary at all. You have no variable `i` in the body of your first loop, so you are doing the same task several times.

To change the 2nd loop you may act as follows (thanks flodel for comment):

```
viol_list = lapply(viol_grp, function(x) vList[vList$Subgroup.Number==x,])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works. 
but a problem. just next line I've something like below. I've a for loop for the i, and more variables are defined inside a if.

at this point I get an error viol_List[[i]] ...subscript out of bounds. 

  if (nrow(viol_List[[i]])>1)
   { subgrp<-viol_List[[i]]$Subgroup.Number}
...........

Comment: A comma was removed in an edit done, although the answer got better through the edit. Can you check it now?

Comment: Why use `seq_long`? If you just loop over `viol_grp`, you'll get its values as names of the output list for free.

Comment: @Amar So you may mark the answer accepted

Answer (score 1):

I imagine what you want to do is split `vList` into separate data frames, based on their `Subgroup.Number`. This will do it very cleanly:

```
viol_list<-split(vList,vList$Subgroup.Number)
```

But if you really want just the groups in `viol_grp`, you'll have to subset:

```
split(vList,vList$Subgroup.Number)[as.character(viol_grp)]
```

But, if `viol_grp` is just all the unique values of `vList$Subgroup.Number`, you don't need it.